# iPad app failing to write back to core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a routine that checks if the last character of a string stored in a Core Data entity is a $ and if so sets a variable 'last' to remember this and then rewrites to Core Data the string with the $ removed.

It does not throw up any errors, and runs through the 'if' routine if the last char is $ but it does not write back to Core Data. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
NSError *error = nil;
observationList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < [observationList count]; loop1++)
{

NSString *classCheckActual = [[observationList objectAtIndex:loop1] valueForKey: @"obsClassName"];
NSString *last = [classCheckActual substringFromIndex:[classCheckActual length] - 1];
NSString *classCheck = @"";

if ([last isEqual: @"$"])
{
  classCheck = [classCheckActual substringToIndex:[classCheckActual length] - 1];
  NSManagedObject *schoolObject = [[self observationList] objectAtIndex:loop1];
  [schoolObject setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", classCheck] forKey:@"obsClassName"];
  NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
}

}
```

Comment: What does `NSLog` tell you about the values of `schoolObject`, `classCheck`, and `context` just before your `save` call?

Comment: Classcheck is correct - the string without the $ but I am unsure how to NSLog the schoolObject or context.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Object: %@, Context: %@", schoolObject, context);`  Mostly I'm looking to verify that they're non-nil.

Comment: Thanks for your help - seems the problem is with the object: Object: (null), Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xa286b80> but I can't see what the problem is. I have added the fetch request to the code above which appears to be working.

Comment: Is it the use of objectAtIndex that is incorrect?

Comment: You use `observationList` in the first part and `[self observationList]` in the second part. Are you sure that this are the same arrays?

Comment: You have spotted it. Thank you so much. If I make it [observationList objectAtIndex:loop1] work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you use two different arrays: `observationList` in the first part and `[self observationList]` in the second part.